# Hibernate transaction does not commit changes to database (SQL Server)

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, nativequery, hibernate-native-query

We have a function in our application that cleans up the database and resets the data, we call a method `cleanup()` which at first deletes all the data from the database and then calls a `sql script` file to insert all the necessary default data of our application. Our application supports Oracle - MySQL and MSSQL, the function works fine on both Oracle and MySQL but doesn't work as it supposed to on MSSQL.

The problem is that it is clearing all the data from the database but not inserting the default data, the first section of the method works fine but the second section doesn't get committed to the database. Here is the function:

```
public boolean cleanup(...){
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // delete and drop sql queries here...

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    // end of first section

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    // insert default data sql queries here...

    tx.commit();
    session.close();
    // end of second section
}
```

The database gets cleared successfully, but the default data is not being inserted to the database. Please let me know what am I doing wrong here. I tried doing both delete and insert sections in one transaction with no luck.

Comment: no exception or anything? have you tried show _sql and see what queries are being sent to Db?